# Configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'root'

Tags: node.js, webpack, bundle, config

I get the following error :

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a
>   configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>    - configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'root'. These properties are valid:    object { alias?, aliasFields?,
>   cachePredicate?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?,
>   enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?,
>   mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, resolver?,
>   symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }

I use [webpack 2.3.2](https://webpack.js.org/).

---

My **webpack.config.js** looks like this :

```
module.exports= {
  entry:'./public/app.jsx',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename:'./public/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    alias:{
      Mod1: 'public/components/mod1.jsx',
      Mod2:'public/components/mod2.jsx',
      Mod3: 'public/components/mod3.jsx'
    },
    extensions: ['*','.js','.jsx']
  },
  module :{
    loaders:[{
      loader :'babel-loader',
      query :{
        presets:['react','es2015','es2017']
      },
      test:/\.jsx?$/,
      exclude:/(node_modules|bower_components)/
    }]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`resolve.root` is Webpack 1 configuration and doesn't exist for Webpack 2.

For Webpack 2 you can use `resolve.modules`: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules

```
module.exports= {
  entry:'./public/app.jsx',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename:'./public/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [__dirname, 'node_modules'],
    alias:{
      Mod1: 'public/components/mod1.jsx',
      Mod2:'public/components/mod2.jsx',
      Mod3: 'public/components/mod3.jsx'
    },
    extensions: ['*','.js','.jsx']
  },
  module :{
    rules:[{
      use : 'babel-loader',
      query :{
        presets:['react','es2015','es2017']
      },
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
    }]
  }
};
```

I've also updated `module.loaders` -> `module.rules` as this is deprecated in Webpack 2.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing LINE 8? Does it through any errors?

As you've probably guessed it is throwing an error as you are trying to set a property which isn't valid.

There is a chance that the instructions you may have followed when configuring webpack is outdated.

Give it a go without LINE 8 and let me know if the problems persist and we can fix it together.